# R : from rpart prediction to a single line result

Tags: r, rpart, c5.0

I am learning R at the moment

I am trying to compare results between different methods C5.0 and rpart
the C5.0 returns like

```
 [1] L R B L R B R R R R R L L B R R R L L L L B R R R L R R B B L B B L L R L R R R L R R B R L R R R L
[51] L B R L R R L R L L R L R R B R R L R R R L L L L
Levels: B L R
```

while rpart returns

```
            B         L          R
1  0.04166667 0.9375000 0.02083333
2  0.04166667 0.9375000 0.02083333
3  0.04166667 0.9375000 0.02083333
4  0.04166667 0.9375000 0.02083333
5  0.04166667 0.9375000 0.02083333
6  0.04166667 0.9375000 0.02083333
7  0.04166667 0.9375000 0.02083333
8  0.04166667 0.9375000 0.02083333
9  0.08163265 0.9183673 0.00000000
10 0.08163265 0.9183673 0.00000000
11 0.04166667 0.9375000 0.02083333
12 0.04166667 0.9375000 0.02083333
13 0.08163265 0.9183673 0.00000000
14 0.08163265 0.9183673 0.00000000
15 0.21428571 0.1904762 0.59523810
16 0.04166667 0.9375000 0.02083333
17 0.08163265 0.9183673 0.00000000
18 0.08163265 0.9183673 0.00000000
19 0.21428571 0.1904762 0.59523810
20 0.21428571 0.1904762 0.59523810
21 0.04166667 0.9375000 0.02083333
22 0.08163265 0.9183673 0.00000000
23 0.21428571 0.1904762 0.59523810
24 0.21428571 0.1904762 0.59523810
25 0.21428571 0.1904762 0.59523810
```

i think the best way is to find the max between prediction between L B and R and put it in new list so it will look like this

```
B  L          R
1  0          0.9375000 0
2  0          0.9375000 0
```

etc

then i dont know how to put it into

```
L
L
R
B
L
B
B
R
```

amyonw can guide me?

Comment: please add your code

Comment: do you want to compare the result of `rpart` and `c5.0` or you want to get prediction?

Comment: Try to add `type = "class"` to `predict.rpart`.